Conditional Lookups Altair
I have found that when looking up data using alt.LookupData, the last data is what is returned. In the example below, when I look up the field parameter in the lookup_data to use in determining the color of the circles it returns the second half of the data [0] * 5 + [1] * 5 (where selection_param==1).
How would I set up a condition so that I use values in field when selection_param is 0 (selection_param==0)?
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Generate data primary data
np.random.seed(42)
primary_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'key': np.arange(10),
    'x': np.random.normal(0, 1, 10),
    'y': np.random.normal(0, 1, 10),
})

# Generate lookup data
lookup_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'key': list(np.arange(10)) * 2,
    'selection_param': [0] * 10 + [1] * 10,
    'field': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] * 2 + [0] * 5 + [1] * 5,
})

# Create chart
alt.Chart(primary_data).mark_circle().encode(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    color='field:N'
).transform_lookup(
    'key',
    from_=alt.LookupData(
        lookup_data, 
        key='key',
        fields=['field']
    )
)


